# async processing with nodejs and rest api calls & express - sequence error

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous

I am using a rest api service to access a node running program and I found the async and await are not retaining sequence. This code does work with a second api call in the func. I think the await and async are getting out of sequence with the second call and that causes the issue.

I tested using a func without a second api call and the sequence is fine, so the problem is related to the CCAPI promise which is generated. I think the "then" is not correct. Also the code in the func accessing the charity API works in isolation so the actual does work and runs also in the whole code but out of sequence.

Any help appreciated.

```
async function checkCharityAPI(searchTerm) {
    const args = { APIKey: myAPIKey, strSearch: searchTerm };
      ccAPI.GetCharitiesByName(args).then(function(result) {
        var charityResult = JSON.stringify(result);
        var charityResultJson = JSON.parse(charityResult);
        console.log(charityResultJson["GetCharitiesByNameResult"]);
        return charityResultJson;
    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log(`Call to ${err.operationName} failed with error: ${err.err}`);
       return null;
    });

}


app.post("/api/checkcharitytest", asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

        var charitySearch = req.body.charitysearch;
        console.log("start api call")
        var charityResult = await checkCharityAPI(charitySearch);
        console.log("end api call")
        res.json({ "charityResult": charityResult})

}));
```

Addition -

I also tried this -

```
var charitySearch = req.body.charitysearch;
        console.log("start api call")
//      var charityResult = await checkCharityAPI(charitySearch);
        checkCharityAPI(charitySearch).then(function(result) {
                console.log("result")
                console.log(result);
                res.json({ "charityResult": result})
        }).catch(function(err) {
           console.log(`Call to ${err.operationName} failed with error: ${err.err}`);
        });

        console.log("end api call")
```

Also I added this - then the seq is corrected by the return value is null despite it being populated in the func -

```
async function checkCharityAPI(searchTerm) {
    const args = { APIKey: myAPIKey, strSearch: searchTerm };
    await ccAPI.GetCharitiesByName(args).then(function(result) {
        var charityResult = JSON.stringify(result);
        var charityResultJson = JSON.parse(charityResult);
        console.log(charityResultJson["GetCharitiesByNameResult"]);
        return charityResultJson["GetCharitiesByNameResult"];
    }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log(`Call to ${err.operationName} failed with error: ${err.err}`);
       return null;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ccAPI.GetCharitiesByName(args)` appears to return a promise, but `checkCharityAPI` **doesn't `await` it**.

You access it with `then`/`catch` instead.

Consequently, the promise returned due to the `async` keyword is entirely independent of the one returned by `ccAPI.GetCharitiesByName(args)`.

Comment: I tried this but the effect was the same (not in seq) - var charitySearch = req.body.charitysearch;
        console.log("start api call")
//      var charityResult = await checkCharityAPI(charitySearch);
        checkCharityAPI(charitySearch).then(function(result) {
                console.log("result")
                console.log(result);
                res.json({ "charityResult": result})
        }).catch(function(err) {
           console.log(`Call to ${err.operationName} failed with error: ${err.err}`);
        });

        console.log("end api call")

Comment: @TrevorLeeOakley — And that's exactly the same problem. You need to change the `checkCharityAPI` function itself.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I added await in the called func and the seq is fine now but the return value is null. That is confusing to me since the seq looks to be correct. I added the new code as an edit in the question.

Comment: That shouldn't return `null`. It should return `undefined` because `checkCharityAPI` has no `return` statement.

Comment: Finally works. I had assumed the return in the await within the called func would return back to the calling func. I moved that to the end and all works.